# Сохранение имени авторизированного пользователя

Tags: javascript

Через
$(function (){
      
$('.menu').append(''+ a +''); }); (a - имя(логин))

вывожу на "navbar" имя авторизированного пользователя (собственно, после авторизации), но когда обновляю страницу, или перехожу на другую страницу сайта - имя пропадает.

Подскажите пожалуйста, как сохранить имя, вне зависимости от того на какую страницу я перейду!? Уже идей нету как это сделать..

Answer (score 0):

localStorage, sessionStorage, cookies, IndexedDB, WebSQL(я бы не использовал)

Вот это вот все можно использовать для хранения данных на стороне клиента(браузера).

Выбирайте что по душе.